# The bot does not respond to the message in any way

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

The user responds to the message that needs to be translated in the format "@BotName The language to be translated into", then the bot outputs the translated text.
Here is an example:
"Дякую"
The user responds to this message in this way
"@Hunch Russian"
The bot replies
"Спасибо" to him

```
import discord
from googletrans import Translator

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
translator = Translator()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('@ИмяБота'):
        text_to_translate = message.content.replace('@ИмяБота ', '')
        lang = text_to_translate.split(' ')[0]
        text = ' '.join(text_to_translate.split(' ')[1:])
        try:
            translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest=lang).text
            await message.channel.send(translated_text)
        except:
            await message.channel.send('Произошла ошибка при переводе. Попробуйте позже.')

client.run('BOT'S TOKEN')
```

The bot does not react at all to the mention, I tried to change the settings in Discord Developer, rewrite the code, but it did not help

Comment: Did you try printing the content of the message....? You should see that mentions are not passed as `@name`, but formatted in a special way

Comment: Are you talking about text_to_translate = message.content.replace('@job name', ")?

Comment: That line as well, yes. I was talking about your initial if-statement but it applies to that line too.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Read my first comment, it quite literally says what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `if message.content.startswith('@ИмяБота')` with `if client.user.mentioned_in(message)`. Hopefully that should help.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but now there is another problem, instead of translating, he writes: "An error occurred during translation. Try again later."

Comment: The current version of googletrans is not working for me, try the following: pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1

Comment: I have already installed, reinstalling did not help

Comment: Weird. Can you get a minimal version of translation working, just by itself, without the bot?

Comment: I mean, how is that?